# Replacing a pattern from Fastq file headers using sed cammand

Tags: sed, fastq

I have a fastq file and i need to edit its header as needed by trinity. My headers are like this :

1. @SRR1561197.**1**.1  HWI-ST1379:100:C29NPACXX:7:1101:**2115:2122**  length=102
2. @SRR1561197.**2**.1  HWI-ST1379:100:C29NPACXX:7:1101:**2202:2120**  length=102
3. @SRR1561197.**3**.1  HWI-ST1379:100:C29NPACXX:7:1101:**2319:2125**  length=102
4. @SRR1561197.**4**.1  HWI-ST1379:100:C29NPACXX:7:1101:**2510:2121**  length=102

In the above headers the **Bold text** keeps on changing with each header other text remains same.
Now i want all header to be replace in one go with a pattern that results in the following headers:

```
@MexD1SRR1561197.1/1
@MexD1SRR1561197.2/1 
@MexD1SRR1561197.3/1
@MexD1SRR1561197.4/1
```

i used the following commands but it didnt changed anything:

```
sed 's/ HWI.*/\/1/g' SRR1561197_1.fastq > change.fastq

sed 's/ HWI.+/\/1/g' SRR1561197_1.fastq > change.fastq
```

Please help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is what you want:

```
sed 's|^@|@MexD1|;  s| HWI.*|/1|g' SRR1561197_1.fastq > change.fastq
```

Note that `HWT` was changed to `HWI`.

Comment: i tried to make my header look like this:

@SRR1561197.1/1

@SRR1561197.2/1 

@SRR1561197.3/1

@SRR1561197.4/1

Comment: @SafinaA.R Can you, using the full power of stackoverflow formatting, revise your question show what the input file header looks like?  As currently formatted, it is unclear to me (a) how many header lines are in each file and (b) where the line breaks are.

Comment: I have a Fastq file containing 22680 sequences. the headers look like as mentioned in the question..

Comment: sed 's/ HWI.*/\/1/g' SRR1561197_1.fastq changed my header but how to add extra letters?

Comment: can anyone please help me with this header replacement:


`@SRR4032388.1.2/2`
`@SRR4032388.2.2/2`
`@SRR4032388.3.2/2`
`@SRR4032388.4.2/2`

I want to change it like this:

`@SRR4032388.1/2`
`@SRR4032388.2/2`
`@SRR4032388.3/2`
`@SRR4032388.4/2`